# Error message: "Could not create Java virtual machine." (Debian10 buster)

Tags: java, linux, debian-buster, openjdk-11

I recently tried running java on debian 10 buster linux. I installed the default-jre and openjdk-11-jdk using the sudo command in the terminal. I confirmed the installations by running the command "sudo apt search openjdk" and it was installed. But when I try to verify the "java version" an error message *could not create the Java Virtual Machine*

How do I go about the process or what am I missing out to run java? Thanks

Comment: What happens when you use `java -version` or `java --version` instead?

Comment: Does it say anything else apart from *"could not create the Java Virtual Machine"*?

Comment: @Stephen C yes it does. "A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit." The above display on a new line after "could not create Java Virtual Machine" error message

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel the second option "java --version" worked.

Comment: OK ... so it is odd that `java version` says that.  On my machine (Ubuntu Focal, OpenJDK Java 11 or 17) running `java version` says `Error: Could not find or load main class version` `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: version`.  Anyway, you have your answer.  Java is installed correctly.  You were just running `java` with an incorrect command line option.

Comment: @Stephen C thanks so much. Funny both commands "java version" & "java --version" now works. I still don't know what I omitted or added initially.

Comment: I solved the problem by closing the console and opening a new console. Strange behavior but it works now.  Here running java 8  with Zorin 16 (Ubuntu 20.04)